# Determine font(s) used in uipasteboard text on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts, uipasteboard

Here is the scenerio:

The user copies random text with mixed fonts.
How do I determine the font(s) used?
When the text is pasted from the UIPasteboard into a textview it correctly shows the mixed fonts, so I believe the information is available.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
textView.text = pasteboard.string;
```

Any Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling [pb string], you may want to use [pb [dataForPasteboardType](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPasteboard/dataForPasteboardType:):@"public.rtf"].

Comment: That doesn't seem to do what I want.  I don't know where the user is pasting from.  Have you used dataForPasteboardType before?  Do you have a sample code?  thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be "public.html" instead of "public.rtf". You should be able to iterate over the types available to see what the other app is putting into the pasteboard, then react accordingly.